# Xamarin Android save webview in pdf

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, itext

I'm developing an app in xamarin for android.

The objective is for the user to fill a document and save it as a PDF.

I have tried this process:

**HTML TO PDF**

I have designed a cshtml file, that contains the same structure as the document, with the input that the user inserted. So far so good, it looks good in the webview. I now wish to convert this to PDF but I can't seem to find a way to convert it.

Is there a way to convert CSHTML to PDF, or somehow convert the content of the webview to PDF?

I have tried an extension called "iTextSharp" to create and manipulate PDF's (my attempt to convert html to a PDF file but the styles and images used in html aren't being applied).

The final objective is to create a PDF file that has the same structure as an HTML Page that I own.

Any way I can accomplish this? Ideas are most welcome

Comment: This may help you : http://www.annalytics.co.uk/android/pdf/2017/04/06/Save-PDF-From-An-Android-WebView/

Comment: Are you trying to make an PDF that contains an "image" representation of the WebView or make a PDF that contains "text".

Comment: I think both would work for me, since I only want to show and save. I used the solution of @MilanG and it works, now I just want to save in a specific path without showing print dialogue screen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could convert the whole `WebView` page content to pdf with below code. Hope it may help you. However, I have just tried this in Simulator.

```
[Activity(Label = "DroidWebview", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@mipmap/icon")]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    WebView myWebView;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        myWebView = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webview);
        myWebView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
        myWebView.SetWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

        myWebView.LoadUrl("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46978983/xamarin-android-save-webview-in-pdf");

        Button myPrintButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.myPrintButton);
        myPrintButton.Click += (sender, e) =>
        {
            var printManager = (PrintManager)GetSystemService(PrintService);
            string fileName = "MyPrint_" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".pdf";
            var printAdapter = myWebView.CreatePrintDocumentAdapter(fileName);
            PrintJob printJob = printManager.Print("MyPrintJob", printAdapter, new PrintAttributes.Builder().Build());
        };
    }
}

public class MyWebViewClient : WebViewClient
{
    public override bool ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, string url)
    {
        view.LoadUrl(url);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's it, big thanks!
Do you know if it's possible save without showing print dialogue screen ?

Comment: Any chance you know the iOS way of doing this?