# Xamarin convert html into pdf using razor templates

Tags: c#, android, pdf, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I wanna to convert Html into pdf and save it, I was able to achieve that doing a webview with the HTML and print it, but this is a manually process, I need this to be automatic, without any action.

I used iTextSharp to do that, with a custom renderer (natively on android), and I have the following code to generate my webView and then print

```
Control.LoadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", new razorModel { Model = Model.MyModel.Instance }.GenerateString(), "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
string fileName = "MyPrint_" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".pdf";
var printAdapter = Control.CreatePrintDocumentAdapter(fileName);
printManager.Print("MyPrintJob", printAdapter, null);
```

**This is working, but I need other way to do that without doing print, anyone can help me ?**

Comment: What do you mean by "using razor template"?

Comment: @Tolulope razor template it's a page cshtml, basically is html

Comment: try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46978983/xamarin-android-save-webview-in-pdf  and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40547892/unable-to-create-pdf-from-html-in-xamarin-android